# The phabricator logo on the left corner broken after upgrade

Tags: phabricator

I just upgraded the phabricator. The logo on the left corner seems to be broken after the upgrade. All other applications are seem to be working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logo was updated may weeks ago, I would recommend clearing cache or making sure the new images are actually on the server. We don't have any other reports on this.